# How to retrieve JSON Data Array from ExtJS Store

Tags: extjs

Is there a method allowing me to return my stored data in an ExtJS Grid Panel exactly the way I loaded it using:

```
var data = ["value1", "value2"]
Store.loadData(data);
```

I would like to have a user option to reload the Grid, but changes to the store need to be taken into account. The user can make changes and the grid is dynamically updated, but if I reload the grid, the data that was originally loaded is shown even though the database has been updated with the new changes. I would prefer not to reload the page and just let them reload the grid data itself with the newly changed store.

I guess I'm looking for something like this:

```
var data = Store.getData();
//data = ["value1", "value2"]
```

after its all said and done. Or is there a different way to refresh the grid with new data that I am not aware of. Even using the proxy still uses the "original" data, not the new store.

Comment: all of these solutions have one basic problem in EXTjs5 http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?290444-store.getData%28%29-returns-quot-id-quot-elment-in-model-data-bug&p=1061271 still dont know if it is bug or feature

Answer (score 53, accepted):

[`Store.getRange()`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-getRange) seems to be exactly what you are searching for. It will return you `Ext.data.Record[]` - array of records. If no arguments is passed, all the records are returned.

Comment: I was looking for Store.getRange().json

Comment: @user291928 : Honestly, you did not specify the format in which you needed the data and this answer seems to have helped.  I suggest you select an answer.

Comment: +1 Also, old link is dead. For others' conveneince: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-getRange

Comment: Jesus! Why `getRange()` ? Why ?

Comment: ok, so you want a 'range' of records, then it returns a 'range' of items... what's not to understand?

Answer (score 54):

A one-line approach:

```
var jsonData = Ext.encode(Ext.pluck(store.data.items, 'data'));
```

Not very pretty, but quite short.

Comment: it working for 3.3.1 as well - is in documentation - I since I found this post I use it with full success and consider it pretty

Comment: This method has been DEPRECTED since 4.0.0

Comment: If you are using a version >= 4.0.0 you have to use Ext.Array.pluck    http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.Array-method-pluck

Answer (score 9):

```
 function getJsonOfStore(store){
        var datar = new Array();
        var jsonDataEncode = "";
        var records = store.getRange();
        for (var i = 0; i < records.length; i++) {
            datar.push(records[i].data);
        }
        jsonDataEncode = Ext.util.JSON.encode(datar);

        return jsonDataEncode;
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
myStore.each( function (model) {
    console.log( model.get('name') ); 
});
```

Comment: you rewrote the 'pluck' function?

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to make any loops and collect/reprocess data. The json object you need is here:

```
var jsonData = store.proxy.reader.jsonData;
```

Comment: this will get the original store data, not the updated store data that could have been modified since

Answer (score 2):

A simple way to do this is

```
var jsonArray = store.data.items
```

So if your JSON store is

```
[{"text": "ABC"}, {"text": "DEF"},{"text": "GHI"},{"text": "JKL"}]
```

Then you can retreive "DEF" as

```
jsonArray[1].data.text
```

In the following code, I noticed that it converts each and every character into an array item.

```
var jsonData = Ext.encode(Ext.pluck(store.data.items, 'data'));
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is another simple clean way:

```
var jsonArr = [];
grid.getStore().each( function (model) {
    jsonArr.push(model.data);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A better (IMO) one-line approach, works on ExtJS 4, not sure about 3:

```
store.proxy.reader.jsonData
```

Comment: Well crap the docs say the above is deprecated, though rawData instead (listed immediately below jsonData) might work, but I've not tested it http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.data.reader.Json-property-jsonData

Answer (score 0):

I run into my share of trouble trying to access data from store without binding it to a component, and most of it was because store was loaded trough ajax, so it took to use the load event in order to read the data. This worked:

```
store.load();
store.on('load', function(store, records) {
    for (var i = 0; i < records.length; i++) {
    console.log(records[i].get('name'));
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I always use `store.proxy.reader.jsonData` or `store.proxy.reader.rawData`

For example - this return the items nested into a root node called 'data':

```
var some_store = Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('some_store_id');
Ext.each(some_store.proxy.reader.rawData.data, function(obj, i){
   console.info(obj);
});
```

This only works immediately after a store read-operation (while not been manipulated yet).

Comment: A bit of sample code, or a link to an example, would be even better!

Comment: should use getters instead of direct references, so above example (already given!?) is best practice.

Comment: @Dawesi the above example implies loading the store (which makes it's proxy load) - vs. accessing the JSON array of any store's proxy, after it had been loaded. best practice still is to read the question, before down-voting correct answers. the store's model and the proxy's JSON array are not the same.

Comment: just so you know: best practice is the use the getters and setters:

`some_store.getProxy().getReader().rawData`

https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.3/modern/Ext.data.reader.Json.html#property-rawData

Answer (score 0):

```
proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        actionMethods: {
            read: 'POST',
            update: 'POST'
        },
        api: {
            read: '/bcm/rest/gcl/fetch',
            update: '/bcm/rest/gcl/save'
        },
        paramsAsJson: true,
        reader: {
            rootProperty: 'data',
            type: 'json'
        },
        writer: {
            allowSingle: false,
            writeAllFields: true,
            type: 'json'
        }
    }
```

Use allowSingle it will convert into array

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the data exactly like what you get by `Writer` (for example ignoring fields with `persist:false` config), use the following code (Note: I tested it in Ext 5.1)

```
  var arr = [];   

    this.store.each(function (record) {
        arr.push(this.store.getProxy().getWriter().getRecordData(record))
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested above I tried below one with fail.

```
store.proxy.reader.jsonData
```

But below one worked for me

```
store.proxy.reader.rawData
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I wanted a javascript jagged array e.g. [["row1Cell1", "row1cell2"],["row2Cell1", "row2cell2"]] based on the contents of the Ext grid store.

The javascript as below will create such an array, dropping the id key in the object which I didn't need.

```
var tableDataArray = [];
Ext.ComponentQuery.query('[name="table1"]')[0].store.each(function(record){
    var thisRecordArray = [];
    for (var key in record.data) {
        if (key != 'id') {
            thisRecordArray.push(record.data[key]);
        }
    }
    tableDataArray.push(thisRecordArray);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one line code it worked for me like charm:

```
var data = (store.getData().getSource() || store.getData()).getRange();
```