# How to write to a memoryproxy in Ext.js

Tags: extjs

I'm trying to use Extjs with a javascript view model. I've had success with loading stores using a JsonReader and the ext.data.memoryproxy class.

However I want to write changes to my Javascript viewmodel.I tried adding a jsonwriter to the writer property of the store but this doesn't work. I get this error:

> uncaught exception: Ext.data.DataProxy: DataProxy attempted to execute an API-action but found an undefined url / function.  Please review your Proxy url/api-configuration.

My Code is:

```
var service = viewmodel.selectedService.analytes;

     var serviceResultsStore = new Ext.data.Store({
        reader: new Ext.data.JsonReader({
            fields: ['Analyte', 'Units', 'Value', 'Rounded', 'PossibleValues']

        }),
        proxy: new Ext.data.MemoryProxy(service),
           writer: new Ext.data.JsonWriter({
                    encode: false,
                    writeAllFields:true
                })
```

Any Help on this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JsonWriter](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.data.JsonWriter) and a [MemoryProxy](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.data.MemoryProxy) won't work well together. They are not intended to.
From the [JsonWriter](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.data.JsonWriter) docs,

> DataWriter extension for writing an
>   array or single Ext.data.Record
>   object(s) **in preparation for executing
>   a remote CRUD action.**

[JsonWriter](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.data.JsonWriter) extends [DataWriter](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.data.DataWriter). From [DataWriter](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.data.DataWriter) docs -

> Ext.data.DataWriter facilitates
>   create, update, and destroy actions
>   between an Ext.data.Store **and a
>   server-side framework.** A Writer
>   enabled Store will **automatically
>   manage the Ajax requests** to perform
>   CRUD actions on a Store.

I am not sure what your high level design/intention around this is but in this case, maybe you can get the records from the store, modify them and commit them back to the store? (You can do all the CRUD operations directly on the store)

Comment: But i have query design problems from my backend programmers. They could not make answer from server fast enough, so pagination in output grid should be make from all taked data by one (but long) request. Does ExtJs have any solutions for such like prorblem? Or ineed to make local memory storage like Array, not Json??

Comment: *My* intention of having a writable memory store would be to avoid the workaround given in http://stackoverflow.com/a/5709096/476074 because it uses private properties.